# Elasticsearch: full-text search and filtering by nested array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

There is a task to make a GUI table that is built based on data from N-join tables in PostgreSQL. 
This GUI table implies sorting and filtering with full-text search capability.

I want to use elastic for this purpose. Prepared this data-structure for elasticsearch:

```
{
  did_user_read: true,
  view_info: {
      total: 1,
      users: [
          { name: 'John Smith', read_at: '2020-02-04 11:00:01', is_current_user: false },
          { name: 'Samuel Jackson', read_at: '2020-02-04 11:00:01', is_current_user: true },
      ],
  },
  is_favorite: true,
  has_attachments: true,
  from: { 
      short_name: 'You',  
      full_name: 'Chuck Norris',
      email: 'ch.norris@example.com', 
      is_current_user: true 
  },
  subject: 'The secret of the appearance of navel lints',
  received_at: '2020-02-04 11:00:01'
}
```

**Please advise how to index this structure correctly so that you can filter and search by nested objects and by nested arrays of objects?**

**For example**, I want to get all the records with these criteria:

```
is_favorite IS false

AND

FULL_TEXT_SEARCH("sam jackson") 
   BY FIELDS 
    users.name,        -- inside of array(!) 
    from.full_name,
    from.short_name

AND

users.is_current_user IS NOT false

AND

ORDER BY received_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping of  elasticsearch index for the  above data-structure should be :

### Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "did_user_read": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "view_info": {
                "properties": {
                    "total": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "users": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "read_at": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                            },
                            "is_current_user": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "is_favorite": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "has_attachments": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "from": {
                "properties": {
                    "short_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "full_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "is_current_user": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            },
            "subject": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "received_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have indexed few of the documents in the same format that you have given in your example.

Search query based on asked criteria should be :

### Search Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "is_favorite": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "view_info.users.is_current_user": true  
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "sam jackson",
                    "fields": [
                        "view_info.users.name",
                        "from.full_name",
                        "from.short_name"
                    ]
                }
            }


        }

    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "received_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Output

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "topics",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "did_user_read": true,
          "view_info": {
            "total": 1,
            "users": [
              {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "read_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:01",
                "is_current_user": false
              },
              {
                "name": "Samuel Jackson",
                "read_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:01",
                "is_current_user": true
              }
            ]
          },
          "is_favorite": false,
          "has_attachments": true,
          "from": {
            "short_name": "You",
            "full_name": "Chuck Norris",
            "email": "ch.norris@example.com",
            "is_current_user": true
          },
          "subject": "The secret of the appearance of navel lints",
          "received_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:03"
        },
        "sort": [
          1580814003000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "topics",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "did_user_read": true,
          "view_info": {
            "total": 1,
            "users": [
              {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "read_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:01",
                "is_current_user": false
              },
              {
                "name": "Samuel Jackson",
                "read_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:01",
                "is_current_user": true
              }
            ]
          },
          "is_favorite": false,
          "has_attachments": true,
          "from": {
            "short_name": "You",
            "full_name": "Chuck Norris",
            "email": "ch.norris@example.com",
            "is_current_user": true
          },
          "subject": "The secret of the appearance of navel lints",
          "received_at": "2020-02-04T11:00:01"
        },
        "sort": [
          1580814001000
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Explaination :

Based on your query this is how search query is constructed :

- `is_favorite IS false and users.is_current_user IS NOT false`

  This is done with the help of `filter` query . Filter is used when we want our documents to meet some conditions but they do not contribute in calculation of score of searched documents . Now since both the query fields are Boolean they wont contribute to calculation to score since there answer is either yes or no.
- `FULL_TEXT_SEARCH("sam jackson") 
             BY FIELDS 
              users.name,        -- inside of array(!) 
              from.full_name,
              from.short_name`

  Here we want to search `sam jackson` and they should be in all 3 fields so 
  `match_phrase` is used.

These three condition are kept in `bool` filter since there is `AND` condition that joins them

- `ORDER BY received_at DESC`

  For this `sort` query is used

**NOTE** : You have to change your data where datetime is present like at read_at, received_at . Currently you are taking format as 2020-02-04 11:00:01 . You just need to change a little bit so that it takes format 2020-02-04T11:00:01 (instead of space use T) while indexing documents in elasticsearch  , since elasticsearch accepts only set of date time formats. You can refer about the formats accepted by date time here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Gald to know it was helpful to you. Can you please upvote the same.